# File visible as normal user but not as Admin

Tags: c#, admin, file-permissions

I am building an universal updater for my company, and when I try to access a mapped network drive, the program throws a file not found exception when run as admin. When the file is run as a normal user the files are visible, but throws an Unauthorized Exception due to the fact that the files are copied to the Program Files (company policy).

Edit

The code that throws the FileNotFound Exception is `FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(rdrInner.GetString(2));` and the Unauthorized Exception is thrown by `File.Copy(pi.RemotePath, pi.Path, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapped drives are part of the user profile, so you need to map the drive whilst logged in as the admin user. This is why using a mapped drive is a bad idea--can't you use a fully qualified UNC path instead? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg465305.aspx for an explanation of UNC paths.

Comment: The problem isn't the mapped drive by itself, I tried replacing the drive part to the UNC path and there was no change.

Comment: Log in as the admin on the machine where you are executing the code. Can you access the UNC path manually through explorer?

Comment: I do not have the admin password, so I cannot verify this, however other applications do access the share when run as admin.

Comment: As it is, your question is close to being closed for being off topic (i.e., nothing to do with C# but entirely to do with your local environment), please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Edit your question to at least include the code where you are getting the file not found exception, and include details of the actual exception, and on which line it occurs. Also ask someone who has the admin password to check that the admin can see the UNC path.

Comment: I added the offending code, however I fail to see how it can help, which is the reason I omitted it in the first place. File.Exists returns false so there is that. As for users with access, the earliest I can get an answer is next monday.

Comment: A new user with the right permissions was created and the task was launched as this new user.